# Is it possible in .net UIAutomation to set a control pattern properties ?

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation

I know that i can retrieve properties of a control in an application through UIAutomation with `GetCachedPropertyValue` and `GetCurrentPropertyValue` methods with `AutomationElement` class. I was wondering, Is it possible to set those properties (like a background color of a Textbox control) to a new value with UIAutomation? If not, is there any other way other than UIAutomation?

Comment: All these stuff are read only can can only be changed by  the thread that created them in the same application, so I don't think there is any way to change them from another process.

Comment: You can set some properties if there is a pattern that supports it like ValuePattern's SetValue or TogglePattern's Toggle. Something like background color is not going to be settable via UI automation, so you might want to describe why you'd want to set another application's textbox's background color. Then maybe we can come up with another way to achieve that goal.

Comment: I wanted to validate and highlight another application textboxes. What do you think about writing to the memory directly (like bits and bytes of background color of a textbox) assuming that i have permission to do that.